# Jquery selector on input field returns prevObject

Tags: jquery

So basically what I'm facing as problem is some strange unexplainable for me behaviour of jquery. So, let's say I've got the following html:

```
<tr onclick='Clicked(this)'></tr>
```

When I use the function like that, everything is, the index is being displayed:

```
function Clicked(x) {
    console.log(x);
    console.log("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
```

Output:

```
><tr onclick="Clicked(this)">...</tr>
>Row index is: 1
```

Let's say now I don't want to register the function directly for the row, but for an input in a cell of it instead, but I'd like to access the same property of the row.
A sample for a row of my table:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='text' class='immediate_update' value='myRandomVal'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And now I'm trying to access the row and cell properties from inside a function assigned for the class of the input... like that:

```
$('.immediate_update').change(function(e)
{
    var cell = $(this).closest('td');
    //I've also tried following, but it's returning the same:
    //$(this).parent();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    console.log(row);
    console.log(row.rowIndex);
});
```

Output:

```
[tr, prevObject: yt.fn.init(1)]
undefined
```

And none of the properties of the row is working... Basically, so
I'd like to ask you what's the cause of the difference between the returned objects and what could be the way to access the row and column index of the cell the input is in - that's what I need to procceed... And also some information in general would be useful, since I've got no idea what's the matter. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowIndex` is a pure javascript if you need to use it you should use `var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0];` but in jquery you can use `.index()`

Demo using `rowIndex`

```js
$('.immediate_update').change(function(e)
{
    var cell = $(this).closest('td');
    //I've also tried following, but it's returning the same:
    //$(this).parent();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    //console.log(row);
    console.log(row.rowIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' class='immediate_update' value='myRandomVal'>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' class='immediate_update' value='myRandomVal'>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' class='immediate_update' value='myRandomVal'>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Demo using `index()`

```js
$('.immediate_update').change(function(e)
{
    var cell = $(this).closest('td');
    //I've also tried following, but it's returning the same:
    //$(this).parent();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    //console.log(row);
    console.log(row.index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' class='immediate_update' value='myRandomVal'>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' class='immediate_update' value='myRandomVal'>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' class='immediate_update' value='myRandomVal'>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Personally , I'm not prefer to mix pure javascript and jquery .. And
>   while you already include jquery you can use it , its much easier

Comment: Pure lack of knowledge is what I'm suffering from.. Thanks a lot! Exactly the type of explanation I needed.

Comment: @D.Petrov You're totally welcome .. Have a great day :-)